# Url routing in server 404 error

Tags: asp.net, routes

I used to do when the routing server. I have a problem.
No problem if **http://myweb.com/news/22*.aspx***
But
If **http://myweb.com/news/22** problem: 404 - File or directory not found.

in local no problem , but server error
Even when .Html or .jsp I use
What is the problem?

id do this :

global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.Add("News", new Route("News/{ID}",new CustomRouteHandler("~/News/News.aspx")));
}
```

CustomRouteHandler.cs class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Compilation;

public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public CustomRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public CustomRouteHandler()
    {
    }

    public string VirtualPath { get; private set; }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext
          requestContext)
    {
        var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath
             (VirtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;
        return page;
    }
}
```

web.config :

```
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler,System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

link :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/news/22" Text="News"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: have you tried adding UrlRoutingModule in <system.webServer> section

Comment: yes . added in <system.webServer> . but not working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in modules section

```
<remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" 
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
               System.Web.Routing, 
               Version=3.5.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

and this in handlers section

```
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
         preCondition="integratedMode" 
         verb="*" 
         path="UrlRouting.axd" 
         type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
               System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Comment: try adding route tester to you application.. this will show it there is any conflict with routes.   http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx